# Зафиксировать объект пока скроллится объект рядом

Tags: jquery, прокрутка, position, fixed

Нужно сверстать следующее:[image: fixing and unfixing block on page scroll]

Левый блок при скролле до этой секции закрепляется сверху до тех пор, пока третий правый блок не сравняется с ним, затем страница продолжает скроллится. Еще необходимо добавить плавный скролл до каждого их правых блоков.

Сам добился только "фиксации" блока, а как его "отпустить", увы, не понимаю.

```
var offsetSection = $('родительский блок').offset().top;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > offsetSection) {
        $('левый блок').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('левый блок').removeClass('fixed');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все то-же самое, просто чуть сложнее. Блок позиционируем с помощью `position:absolute;`:

Я бы не рекомендовал считать высоты в начале скрипта, если высота блоков не фиксирована.

```js
var offsetSection = $('.right').offset().top;
var heightSection = $('.right').offset().top + $('.right').height() - $('.left').height();


$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > offsetSection) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < heightSection) {
      $('.left div').removeClass('bottom');
    } else {
      $('.left div').addClass('bottom');
      $('.left').height($('.right').height())
    }
    $('.left div').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('.left div').removeClass('fixed');
  }
})
```

```css
body{padding:0;margin:0;}

.block {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 20px 10%;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 10px;
  position: relative
}

.b {
  clear: both;
  height: 100px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 20px 5%;
  top: 0;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
  width: 80%;
   margin: 20px 10%;
}

.right+.b {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="b"></div>

<div class="left">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>


<div class="b"></div>
```

Comment: Все работает. Спасибо! Есть один нюанс: в моем случае левый и правый блоки при ширине окна менее 990px становятся друг над другом, а скрипт делает так, что высота левого блока равняется правому. Я попытался сделать вот что:

    `$(window).on("resize", function() {
 if (this.width <= 990) {
  $(".right").height("auto");
 }
    })`

Не работает.

Comment: @MichaelKopytin во-первых используйте  `window.matchMedia( "(min-height: 990px)" )`; во-вторых попробуйте `$(".right").css("height","auto")`